# selenium + chrome headless=new : waiting for jquery / ajax completion

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Using .net 7 and selenium chrome webdriver, I just came across this new chrome option (--headless=new) for the new headless mode.

As I'm trying this new option, my actual test code used for waiting till ajax/jquery is completed don't work anymore :

```
while (true) 
    {

      var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)(driver.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return window.jQuery != undefined && jQuery.active === 0");
      if (ajaxIsComplete)
        break;
      Thread.Sleep(1500);

    }
```

Switching back to my usual "--headless" works perfectly fine.

Maybe there's a whole better solution to do this. I'm pretty sure it's the window.jQuery != undefined part of the query that is problematic as it will never return true with this new headless option enabled.

Thanks!